# Restoring SharePoint Welcome / Home Page to Default

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a `SharePoint` site that has not content yet. All I have done is create a feature that applies my own custom styling (via `visual studio`). I was experimenting with some of the features of `SharePoint` and somehow seem to have removed the content of the welcome page.

Here is what the page looks like now:

[image]

Here is what it used to look like (I found this on google images so the styling of course doesn't match mine, but you get the idea of the kind of content that used to be there):

[image]

This is the code from the `FeatureActivated` function that caused this change (I was trying to change the welcome page):

```
foreach (SPWeb web in siteCollection.AllWebs) {
    var root = web.RootFolder;
    if (root != null)
    {
        root.WelcomePage = @"Layouts/AccessFolder/HomePage.aspx";
        root.Update();
    } 

    //set master page (custom styling)
}
```

How do I revert these changes becuase currently I cannot even add web parts when I try to edit the page. Is it just a cas eof running that same code again but changing the `WelcomePage` URL? If so how do I find out what the original master page is called.

Note: I do not have access to `SharePoint Designer`.

Comment: Have you tried going to the SitePages Library from SiteContents option and create a brand new WebPage from the UI itself? You can then mark it as your HomePage.

Comment: Thanks for the response. For anyone with the same issue: I went to the SiteContents page, and from there I saw a page called `Home` (I cant remember if I created this page previously or if it was already there). I clicked on that page and when it loaded I went to `Edit Page` and then `Set as Home Page`.  If you want to write an answer to this, I'd be glad to accept it!

Comment: Ok. I'll post an answer to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint allows us to change the homepage of a site from the UI itself. The process is:-

- Go to the SiteContents.
- Open the page you want to set as the new home page.
- Select the **Page Tab** from the above and then click the **Mark HomePage/Set as Home Page** option.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer!